# Add non-editable label after what user types in UITextField - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I would like to have a text field where the user can enter their weight in pounds. Currently, it is taking input the way I want, but I would like to add a **non-editable** "lbs" string that is always shown after what the user types (i.e. '140 lbs' if the user types 140), but doesn't interfere with the value received from the textFieldDidEndEditing. In a way, it would essentially be a static label that moves as the user types. What would be the best way to do this? I am using Objective-C, by the way.

Comment: You can also check on rightView and rightViewMode properties of UITextField as a clean approach if it fits your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `UILabel` onto your `UITextField` and make it `userInteractionEnabled = NO`. And you have to calculate your text's width on each enter. When your `textField.text` gets wider move your label. And here's the helper method which helps you to calculate your `string`'s size depending on font

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont*)font boundingRectToHeight:(CGFloat)height {
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    NSDictionary * attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName:font,
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle};

    CGRect textRect = [self boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX, height)
                                         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:attributes
                                         context:nil];

    return textRect.size;
}
```